# difference between two questions with the same meaning

Tags: difference

In a *Goehthe Zertifikat* letter example, it is said:

> Wann **fängt** die Party **an**? **Sagen** Sie mir noch **Bescheid**?

I believe that **both** questions have the **same meaning** in this regard, why is the second question asked? What is the difference between  both questions?

Comment: The sentences have totally different meanigs. The first asks for the time a party begins, the second urges someone to inform someone else.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich why "...to inform someone else"? I would think, to confirm the first question: "Let me know when the party starts" (Bescheid über den Party beginn geben).

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Bescheid geben = to inform so. But why **jemand anderes** (someone else). "Sagen Sie mir noch Bescheid" means **inform ME** and not "to inform someone else." Or do I not understand your comment?

Comment: Es sind zwei Personen involviert. Es gibt also jemand (Person 1) jemand anderem (Person 2) Bescheid. Und natürlich kann der ein oder andere Jemand auch ich, du, er, sie oder wer auch immer sein.

Comment: I understand your points but I still think both questions ask for the same bit of information which is  : when does the party start ? , and the second question should be dropped as it constitutes a repetition unless by the second question they ask for a reminder of when is the party going to take place, but i'm not all convinced by it.

Comment: @Ahmed, your analysis is correct. Still this hasn't to do with the meanings of the sentences. Furthermore, such a redundancy is nothing special about the german language. It is, if at all, a matter of culture or style.

Answer (score 3):

This **two** sentences **have not** the **same meaning**!

The first question asks, "when does the party start?" and in the second question, the questioning one wants, that the questioned person gives notice, when the party starts ("let me know when the party starts").

In an english conversation it would look like:

> "When does the party start? Will you let me know?"

But you can just use the first question without the second:

> "When does the party start?"

Comment: I think a better translation for *Sagen Sie mir noch Bescheid?* is *Will you let me know?*. *Noch* here refers to the future.

Comment: You are right @RHa, I took it over like that.

Answer (score 1):

The two sentences have quite different meanings:

> Wann fängt die Party an?

This sentence quite plainly asks when the party starts.

> Sagen Sie mir noch Bescheid?

This sentence, however, modifies the above question - it indicates the asker does not necessarily need to know right away. Especially due to the "noch", this sentence means "Will you inform me in time (before the party starts)?"

This means the asker will accept if they do not get a definitive time right away, but what they want right away is at least a confirmation that they will be informed about the starting time in time, by the person being asked.